# Could a geomagnetic storm disrupt the functioning of nerves?

Tags: electromagnetism, biophysics

It is known that geomagnetic storms can cause power grid outages. Can they also disrupt the functioning of nerves/the nervous system?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on the biology site.

Comment: No. The electromagnetic fields are far too weak. I have heard if you move your head around in a really strong magnet (MRI grade, multiple Tesla), you get momentary visual effects. But I haven't had a chance to try it.

Comment: A really strong electric field can make your hair stand on end without affecting your nerves. [Kylie's Hair Standing on End](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WS9ISUXBsa8).

Comment: A better question might be "How can a strong solar storm disrupt a power grid, and yet not affect the human nervous system?"

Comment: The physics of organisms is better asked at this site.

Comment: Voting to re-open. This is a perfectly clear physics-based question with a straightforward answer.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are two key differences between power grids and biological nervous systems:

1. Nerves are not electrical conductors like wires. Nerve signals are transmitted by biochemical processes that create imbalances of positive and negative ions which travel along a nerve. These processes *can* be affected by a large enough magnetic field, but this requires field strengths many orders of magnitude greater than those produced in a geomagnetic storm. The maximum field strength produced in a typical MRI machine is between $1$ and $10$ Tesla - for comparison, the field strengths involved in even the largest geomagnetic storms are a few hundred nanoteslas. You are exposed to far higher magnetic fields than this if you walk under an electric power line or hold a fridge magnet.
2. Nerves are much shorter than power lines. The reason geomagnetic storms affect power lines is that the variation in the Earth's magnetic field can cause power surges in those lines over distances of hundreds of kilometres. Even in a good electrical conductor, the effect over a few tens of centimetres is negligible.