# Which would induce more current/voltage in the human body - a geomagnetic storm, or walking past a fridge magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

With the latter scenario, the magnet is an ordinary fridge magnet stuck to the fridge, and the person walks past the fridge. The question is which scenario would have a greater effect on the body.

Comment: Very much related [Could a Geomagnetic storm disrupt the functioning of nerves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/792040/23615), at least the answer there likely will help you realize the magnitudes of difference between your situations.